# Formula of average datetime in crystal report (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am new in crystal report, i wanna calculate the average of datetime in crosstab but i could not. I don't know how to write a formula ... help me please

Comment: What means average of datetime? What is average of 1900-01-01 15:30 and 2015-01-13 11:07 for example?

Comment: What do you mean by average of a date time post some   example data

Comment: Avg(00:30:22,00:28:11,20:45:21,...)

Comment: maybe firt,i should convert date to number(seconds) and calculate the Avg after convert again to datetime ...but how can  i do this formula in crosstab ?

Comment: in summarizes fields i didn't get Average

Comment: You need to use embeeded summary

Comment: what you mean Siva ..i didn't get it

Comment: to write and edit the formula in cross tab you need to write in embeeded formula